About Diophantine approximations of two irrational numbers at once
If we want to approximate a rational number $\frac{r}{s}$ by a different rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ then note that there exists an integer $q_0$ such that
$$\left| \frac{r}{s} - \frac{p}{q}  \right| \geq \frac{1}{qq_0} $$
Rephrased differently, this just means that for any integers $p,q$ the difference $\left| q \frac{r}{s} -p  \right|$ is bounded from below.
This gives us a tool for proving irrationality! A number $\alpha$ is irrational, if there exists a sequence of rationals $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ such that
$$\left| q_n\alpha - p_n  \right| < \frac{1}{q_n^{\delta}}, \quad \delta > 0 $$
My question is, could we extend this result to two potentially irrational numbers $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$? That is, if we have
$$\left| q_n’\alpha_1 + q_n’’\alpha_2- p_n  \right| \rightarrow 0, \quad n \rightarrow \infty $$
where $q_n’, q_n’’, p_n$ are positive integers could we say, that both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are irrational? What if $\alpha_1$ is known to be irrational, could we then say that $\alpha_2$ is also irrational?
My intuition tells me that both answers are no. But assume that $\alpha_2$ is rational, then we can “split” $p_n$ into $p_n’ +p_n’’$ in such a way that by the earlier remark $q_n’’\alpha_2-p_n’’$ is bounded from below by a positive value, and that $q_n’\alpha_1-p_n’$ is positive, making the whole absolute value also bounded from below. Is such a “split” possible?
